# Can we declare global variable in Power BI? I want to create url column in table and domain will be different for each environment (Dev, QA, Prod)

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource, power-bi-report-server

I am creating power bi reports in which I am showing table which will contain product list. I am creating custom column for url. I want to set it in any configuration or global setting so that I can set different domain for each environment similar to connection string we use.

Answer (score 3):

we can set domain in parameter and later change in parameter setting. To achieve this we need to follow below steps:

1. Go to dataset and click on transform data
2. Click on manager parameter and add new parameter
   [image]
3. Select type as text assign name
   [image]
4. Once added add add column tab and user your parameter name to embed in column value
   [image]
5. Once you publish you will be able to edit it for each environment you configure and will not change on publish
   [image]

Please refer this video if more clarity required
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zeeiSFdWCrY&t=172s&ab_channel=Curbal

Answer (score 1):

That's pretty straight forward:

```
environment = "http://www.development.com/'
```

and then

```
table[url] = environment & table[connect]
```

Comment: Thank you Peter for the quick reply i am very new to power bi i want to know can I declare this environment variable somewhere outside the dataset so that i need not change every time I publish it and use pipeline for different environments similar to connection strings we use for dataset